# Link colour with integer ggplot2

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I am new with ggplo2 and I don't manage to reproduce something I was using with native `plot` function : basically I add points to a plot iteratively and I want the new points to be added with a colour changing also iteratively.

MWE:

```
pts = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
plot(pts, pch = 19)
for(i in 2:5) {
   pts = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
   points(pts, col = i, pch = 19)
}
```

which gives:
[image]

while with ggplot2 I have:

```
pts = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
p <- ggplot(pts, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
print(p)
for(i in 2:5) {
   pts = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
   p <- p + geom_point(data = pts, aes(colour = i))
   print(p)
}
```

[image]
which does not give the same thing. I have thought using `scale_colour_hue(5)` instead of `aes(colour=i)` to specify I want 5 different distinguishable colours, but I got an error :

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

thanks !

Comment: Generally, ggplot2 works best if you put all data that needs to be plotted the same way in the same dataframe first.

Comment: unfortunately in my real case the data are generated iteratively while I'd like to have the plot updated after each new generation and not waiting for the end of the process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the iterative nature of your case, this might be a solution. I have added the iteration to the data, to have all information for a certain point contained in the relevant dataset. Then I used `factor(i)` to color it. You were on the right way with `aes(color=i)`, but as i equals 5 at the end of the iteration all dots get colored as 5 (with the exception of the first iteration, as they have no color-mapping.

Edit: created a column 'iteration' with factor levels 1 to the number of iterations in each dataset and forced all levels to display in the scale parameter.

```
set.seed(124)
n_iterations <- 5
pts = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), 
                 y = rnorm(10),
                 iteration=factor(1,levels=1:n_iterations)
)
p <- ggplot(pts, aes(x,y, color=iteration)) + geom_point()+
  scale_colour_discrete(drop=FALSE) + #forces all levels to display
  ylim(c(-2.5,2.5)) #keeps plot limits constant

for(i in 2:5) {
  pts = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), 
                   y = rnorm(10), 
                   iteration=factor(i,levels=1:n_iterations))
  p <- p + geom_point(data = pts)
  print(p)
}
```

[image]

Iterated images:
[image]

Comment: it almost good, but the colors associated with a number change, ie if you look at intermediate plots 3 won't be associated with green. I need to keep this consistency because at iteration i indeed I add points to layers i and i-1

Comment: See my edit - I've tinkered a bit more with forcing all factor levels to be present and displayed.

Comment: `scale_colour_discrete(drop=FALSE)` makes the difference ; I tried to specify all the levels in `factor(` but this was not enough, thanks !